# MVVM architecture WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a little architecture problem with `MVVM` in WPF. I am having `View` which contains option to write some code or scan `QRCode` with computer`s camera.
If user choose to not scan the code, I can bind`Command` and there is no problem.

Problem is there when user choose to scan qrcode.
When user press scan code part of screen is being collapsed and camera shows on the screen. I have to do it in `View` code behind, so the code I am getting in `View` which is not good in MVVM.

Here how View`s code look like:

```
private void Scan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_finalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                _finalVideo.Stop();
            }

            _finalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(_cameraDevices[CamerasList.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);

            _finalVideo.NewFrame += (s, a) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image img = (Bitmap)a.Frame.Clone();
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
                    bitmapImage.EndInit();
                    bitmapImage.Freeze();
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {
                        CameraStream.Source = bitmapImage;
                        ReadQrCode(bitmapImage);
                    }));
                }
                catch
                {
                    //exc
                }
            };

            _finalVideo.Start();
        }
```

How I can solve that problem with `MVVM`?

Comment: What makes you think having code behind in the view is bad ? It's perfectly ok to have such code if it's doing UI related work - which is what you're doing.

Comment: I typically just write an interface to abstract such external input/output stuff. So you end up with an `ICommand Scan` property that when executed calls a `Task<QrCode> ReadQrCodeFromCameraAsync` method on an interface. In your unit tests, you make a fake implementation of this interface.

Answer (score 4):

That's quite simple, once you get the grip of it and know the difference between a "user control" and a view.

The first statement is, that ideally the code behind should be empty for a view. This is true.

However, this do not apply for user controls. User controls can and should have code behind, because they need to work self-sustained and do not have their logic extracted into some view model class.

So what's the difference between a user control and a view? Yes, they both generally derive on `UserControl`, but this do not make a view a user control by default. What matters is that, a view is very specific piece of UI made for **one application** which is **very unlikely** to be reused in other application.

For example, a `CustomerDetailView` or `CustomerDetailPage` in Application A is going to be different than the same view for Application B, because Application B will likely have different requirements for a `CustomerDetailView`.

A user control on the other side is meant to be reusable across applications, for example `DatePicker`, `CalendarControl` or a `CameraControl`. This control can be used in multiple applications that may need a camera for example.

Important thing here is, that the "user control" has no knowledge of your application structure, so no viewmodels, no business/domain models etc. If you want to allow ViewModels to bind to your user control (`ICommand` for starting and call backs for example, or bind the resulting picture to the ViewModel), then you put dependency properties into your user control.

When you use this user control in your application, you just bind your view model to these dependency properties (DP) and you got your abstraction.

TL;DR: 
Code behind in a view is **bad**, code behind in a user control is **necessary**.

Comment: Code behind in a View is quite OK as long as it is presentation related. Your distinction of Control vs View is useful, but don't pin it to specific classes.