# How to access View members from within ViewModel when using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

I've searched the web and haven't come across any direct explanation to this simple question...

I have a UWP app I'm working on and I simply need to know how to, for example, access a Grid element or Textblock element located on within the View's XAML. Every article I come across is strictly about data binding. I'm not looking to bind data. I'm simply looking to get my hands on those elements located within my View so that I can manipulate them.

One major issue I've come across is finding a MVVM way to manipulate a RichEditBox from within my ViewModel, for example. This particular control cannot be manipulated completely through XAML and requires the use of code.

So yeah, basically, how do I get a reference to these objects from the ViewModel?

Comment: You need to learn more about MVVM first. The idea behind MVVM ist to separate the view (ui) from the viewmodel (presentation logic). That being said, a ViewModel is unaware of anything that happens inside the view, so the answer is: Not at all. You have commands and notifiable properties, that's what you use to communicate with the view. There are other tools you can utilize to work around it, like attached properties. Attached properties can be attached to a user control in XAML and you can bind property or commands to it.

Comment: If you have a complex enough and generic solution, you can make a user control. in user controls you can use code behind to put all the logic required and then expose dependency properties to bind commands and properties to it. See my answers on similar questions about user controls and code behind http://stackoverflow.com/a/35983746/455493 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35395128/455493

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of MVVM is to separate the view and the view model.

If there is something you cannot do with data binding from the view model you can always put code in the code behind for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can not be strict and using only the MVVM pattern, there are some situations where you need to manipulate View elements for instance when using third party components.
For such scenario, using for instance LightMVVM for UWP. When instantiating your ViewModel you can pass a reference to your View, the best approach would be using a sort of dependency injection, nevertheless, here is some implementation suggestion:

```
    public abstract class BaseViewModel<TPage> 
    where TPage : class
{
    public TPage View { get; private set; }
    ///this is a method but it could be a constructor as well..
    public TViewModel SetupParentPage<TViewModel>(TPage p)
        where TViewModel : class
    {
        if (View == null)
        {
            View = p;                                       
        }
        return (this as TViewModel);
    }
}
```

Now what you have to do is inherit your ViewModel from BaseViewModel

Then you can access your page's controls by using:

```
View.FindName("YourControlName") as YourControlType;
```